# Python: How to output word batches of 10 while using a list?

Tags: python

I have list.txt which is ~4000 words like this:

```
cool
fast
smart
welcome
coder
word
nine
stacked
jokes
funny 

haha
lol
qwerty
computer
keyboard
```

I would like to take all input in this list and putting it in another text document ( output.txt ) in batches of 10 with a blank line in between, like this;

```
cool fast smart welcome coder word nine stacked jokes funny 

haha lol qwerty computer keyboard 

blablabla...
```

Anyone that could help me out here?

I was thinking about using a list, but i have no idea how to make it into batches of 10 + add the blank line in between each one!

Comment: Yes but i would like for them to not be stacked on top of eachother, but rather be in a single sentence

Comment: What does it look like in the end? Is the last group complete (i.e. has 10 words) and is it followed by an empty line?

Comment: The output would be something like this:


cool fast smart welcome coder word nine stacked jokes funny 

haha lol qwerty computer keyboard 


I just want my list to be formatted differently than it currently is 

Instead of the text being stacked i want it to basically be sentances of 10 words long

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, i don't really know of any other way of wording it haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read in the words from `test.txt` and output them to `result.txt`.

There will be `NO_WORDS` words on each line, separated by a space and each line will be separated by a blank line.

```py
NO_WORDS = 10

with open("test.txt") as file:
    data_in = file.readlines()

data_out = [
    [item.replace("\n", " ") for item in data_in[idx : idx + NO_WORDS]] + ["\n\n"]
    for idx in range(0, len(data_in), NO_WORDS)
]

print(data_out)

with open("result.txt", "w") as file:
    [file.write("".join(items)) for items in data_out]
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you norie

Answer (score 0):

```
string_batches =  [string[start:start+10] for start in range(0, len(string), 10)]
```

This returns an array with equal strings size

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
from typing import Iterator

NO_WORDS = 10


def group(n, gen):
    gen = iter(gen)

    while True:
        grp = None

        try:
            for i in range(n):
                if grp is None:
                    grp = []
                grp.append(next(gen))
            yield grp

        except StopIteration:
            if grp is not None:
                yield grp
            break


def non_empty_lines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != "":
            yield line.strip()


def main():
    with open('list.txt', 'r') as in_file, open('result.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for grp in group(NO_WORDS, non_empty_lines(in_file)):
            print(" ".join(grp), file=out_file)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```